# How do you search each line in a file for all contents of a list?

Tags: python, debugging, arp

I'm still new to Python and having some issues searching a file for the contents of a list. What I'm needing is to search an entire file for each string in a list. So I need to iterate through each element of a list for each line in a file and look for matches. If it helps, I'm trying to match mac addresses with contents of an arp table. The macs I'm looking for are in a list. The entire arp table is in a file.

Here's my code that is not working:

```
mac_addr = []  
ipaddr = []

with open('arp_table_output.txt','r+') as myArps:
    for line in myArps:
        val = line.split()
        for x in mac_addr:
            if x in line:
                ipaddr.append(val[0])
```

Here's an example of a line in the arp file:

```
10.10.10.4     00:18:32   38ea.a792.1e62  Dynamic    ARPA  Bundle-Ether2.3
```

Here's a snippet of what mac_addr looks like:

```
 0100.0ccc.cccc  
 0100.0ccc.cccd  
 0180.c200.0000  
 0180.c200.0001  
 0180.c200.0002  
 0180.c200.0003  
 0180.c200.0004  
 0180.c200.0005  
 0180.c200.0006  
 0180.c200.0007    
 0180.c200.0008  
 0180.c200.0009
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"not working"*? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: I'm not getting any traceback errors, just not the expected output. For example: 
the mac_addr list will contain a string such as 38ea.a792.1e62. I need to search the arp file, see if its there, and if so grab the ip address and store it in a new list.

Comment: what does mac_addr look like?You want to append the ip if the mac is in the line?

Comment: are all those separate strings in your mac_addr list?

Comment: This seems to work just fine, with `mac_addr = ['38ea.a792.1e62']`, `ipaddr` contains a list of all the ip addresses with that mac address.

Comment: Padraic Cunningham - Yes, that is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: mac_addr is a list of multiple strings

Comment: So what is the expected output, and what do you get instead?

Comment: your problem is most likely that there's a minor difference between the values within your `mac_addr` list and the value you want to match against in each file's line. Given that you give a made up example of the `mac_addr` list, and not the exact output, we can't help you find out what that difference might be. So use the snippet I made as an answer, which should help you find out what matches and what doesn't match. Then the real fix should be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I'd advice you would be to first remove all unnecessary data from the line, so you get exactly what you're looking for:

```
addr = [ x for x in line.split(" ") if x ][2]
```

and then printout that value along with the values in your list:

```
for target in mac_addr:
    print("'{}' vs '{}' -> {}".format(addr, target, addr == target))
```

so you can check how they differ.

In the end:

```
with open('arp_table_output.txt','r+') as myArps:
    for line in myArps:
        # select *ONLY* the lines that contain the IP and MAC information in the input file
        if "Dynamic" in line:
            # here we extract the IP and the MAC from the line (python3 syntax)
            ip, _, mac, *_ = [ x for x in line.split(" ") if x ]
            # if you prefer python2: use `x, _, y, _, _, _ = …`

            # Test to printout what works and what does not. If none pass, the "in" test below will fail.
            for target in mac_addr:
                print("'{}' vs '{}' -> {}".format(mac, target, mac == target))

            if mac in mac_addr:
                ipaddr.append(ip)
```

Comment: I'm getting invalid syntax error for the If statement. I don't see why. I'm using python 2.6

Comment: sorry, I made a typo, I forgot one closing parenthesis, now fixed.

Comment: ah, I didn't catch that. I was confused haha

Comment: mac,_,ip,_,_,_ = [ x for x in line.split() if x ]
ValueError: too many values to unpack
Do you know a solution for this by chance?

Comment: check that the line you want to split matches the format. One problem maybe that your file has lines that are not to be parsed, then try adding `if "Dynamic" in line:` just after the `for` to only parse those (or `if "ARPA"` or whatever else is relevant). Or maybe all your lines are not having the same grouping, and then chances are that ip and mac do not have the same position.

Comment: After messing with the source file and ensuring everything was spaced properly and all the junk was gone, I finally got this to work. Thank you very much for the assistance!